# xsl render children of different parent nodes and sort

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, parent-child, nodes

I'm a newbie to XML/XSL and could use some need help displaying and sorting values that are stored within the child nodes of two different parents (i.e., the data are "cousins").

The XML file includes a schedule of events happening today in different rooms of our building. Each event is represented by the `<event>` tag, which contains `<space>` and `<event_details>` nodes, each of which has child nodes where the values I want to display and sort are stored. It basically has the following structure (using an example with two records below, with closing tags removed for readability):

```
<schedule>

    <event>
        <space>
            <space_name>Room 210
        <event_details>
            <event_name>English Literature
            <event_startandendtime>9:20am to 10:30am
    <event>
        <space>
            <space_name>Room 103
        <event_details>
            <event_name>Advanced Calculus
            <event_startandendtime>8:00am to 9:10am
```

Using XSL, I am trying to output the schedule with the events listed in order by date in the following format:

**event_startandendtime, event_name, space_name

event_startandendtime, event_name, space_name**

For example:

**8:00am to 9:10am, Advanced Calculus, Room 103

9:20am to 10:30am, English Literature, Room 210**

So far, I've been unsuccessful. In one attempt to code it, I can generate a sorted list but I can't get the space_name to appear. In another attempt, I can get the space_name, but can't get a sorted list, nor do I have much control over where to place the space_name.

Is this a straightforward coding task or a much more complicated one for a newbie? Thanks a lot for any directions you can point me in!

BeiJi

UPDATE: I think I got it with all your help! Here's some of the code...

[Screenshot of XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYG2m.png)

[Screenshot of XSL Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnDEH.png)

BROWSER VIEW:

```
08:00 - 09:10 : Advanced Calculus, Room 103
09:20 - 10:30 : English Literature, Room 210
13:00 - 15:20 : Beginning Calculus, Room 305
```

Conversion of date from 24 hours to 12 hours not working yet, but thanks again!

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? -- "*In one attempt to code it, I can generate a sorted list but I can't get the space_name to appear.*" Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. -- "*closing tags removed for readability*" That's not a good idea - see: [mcve].

Comment: Hi everyone, Thanks so much for your suggestions and for the link to the guidelines for giving appropriate examples (this is my first post, so I wasn't aware). I only didn't post my code because I was trying to simplify the task conceptually, to get advice whether it would be possible with xsl for-each or xsl sort, given the nesting of the nodes. I'll try to understand the code you posted to see if I can accomplish something like that for this task (I'm not much of a programmer). Thanks again, BeiJi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data provider is being unkind to you by not structuring the data properly - and you are being unkind to us by not providing an example we could use for testing as is.

Still, here's a way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="event">
            <!-- 1. AM before PM -->
            <xsl:sort select="contains(substring-before(event_details/event_startandendtime, ' '), 'pm')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <!-- 2. Sort by hour (convert 12 to 0) -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(event_details/event_startandendtime, ':') mod 12" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <!-- 3. Sort by minute -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(substring-after(event_details/event_startandendtime, ':'), 1, 2)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
             <!-- output -->           
            <xsl:value-of select="event_details/event_startandendtime"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="event_details/event_name"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="space/space_name" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <event>
    <space>
      <space_name>Room 210</space_name>
    </space>
    <event_details>
      <event_name>English Literature</event_name>
      <event_startandendtime>9:20am to 10:30am</event_startandendtime>
    </event_details>
  </event>
   <event>
    <space>
      <space_name>Room 305</space_name>
    </space>
    <event_details>
      <event_name>Beginning Calculus</event_name>
      <event_startandendtime>1:00pm to 3:20pm</event_startandendtime>
    </event_details>
  </event>
 <event>
    <space>
      <space_name>Room 103</space_name>
    </space>
    <event_details>
      <event_name>Advanced Calculus</event_name>
      <event_startandendtime>8:00am to 9:10am</event_startandendtime>
    </event_details>
  </event>
</root>
```

the (rendered) result will be:

```
8:00am to 9:10am, Advanced Calculus, Room 103
9:20am to 10:30am, English Literature, Room 210
1:00pm to 3:20pm, Beginning Calculus, Room 305
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Your contribution helped me solve the problem and not completely lose my mind. As a beginning coder, everything takes forever! :)  I'll post my test code (which is a snippet of the actual XML and a simplified version of the XSL). I'm still working on converting from 24-hour time, but this really gets us where we need to be! Thanks! -BeiJi

Comment: Do you mean **to** 24-hour time? See if this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359880/formatting-a-string-to-digital-time/36365035#36365035

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your xml file

xml

```
<Root>
<event>
    <space>
        <space_name>Room 210</space_name>
    </space>
    <event_details>
        <event_name>English Literature</event_name>
        <event_startandendtime>9:20am to 10:30am</event_startandendtime>
    </event_details>
</event>
<event>
    <space>
        <space_name>Room 103</space_name>
    </space>
    <event_details>
        <event_name>Advanced Calculus</event_name>
        <event_startandendtime>8:00am to 9:10am</event_startandendtime>
    </event_details>
</event>
</Root>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Room", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Event", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement _event in doc.Descendants("event"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                   (string)_event.Descendants("space_name").FirstOrDefault(),
                   (string)_event.Descendants("event_name").FirstOrDefault(),
                   (string)_event.Descendants("event_startandendtime").FirstOrDefault()
               });
            }

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Room"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Time"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Event"))
                .CopyToDataTable();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: C# using XML Linq.

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I think I got it with all your help! Here's some of the code...

XML: [Screenshot of XML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8y0f.png)

XSL: [Screenshot of XSL Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgtRJ.png)

BROWSER VIEW:

08:00 - 09:10 : Advanced Calculus, Room 103
09:20 - 10:30 : English Literature, Room 210
13:00 - 15:20 : Beginning Calculus, Room 305

Conversion of date from 24 hours to 12 hours not working yet, but thanks again!